# How to use s:set as param to s:push making static method call in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I tried :

```
<s:set name="ordersymbol" value="EURUSD" var="ordersymbol"/>
    <s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO(%{#ordersymbol})">

<s:set name="ordersymbol" value="EURUSD" var="ordersymbol"/>
    <s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO(#ordersymbol)">

<s:set name="ordersymbol" value="EURUSD" var="ordersymbol"/>
    <s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO(ordersymbol)">

<s:set name="ordersymbol" value="EURUSD" var="ordersymbol"/>
    <s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO(%{ordersymbol})">
```

Neither of the above four worked, the method always get null parameter.

Although if I try

```
<s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO('EURUSD')">
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's an old question... But:

The reason in doesn't work is that "value is an object."  The correct <s:set/> would be:

```
<s:set var="ordersymbol" value="'EURUSD'" />
```

and the correct <s:push/> is the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
<s:set name="ordersymbol" value="EURUSD" var="ordersymbol"/>
    <s:push value="@dao.positions@positionsO('%{#ordersymbol}')">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an alternative by the way.

```
<s:set value="@dao.positions@positionsO('EURUSD')" var="symbol1"/>
    <s:push value="#symbol1">
```

In case of using an iterator

```
<s:iterator value="#{'EURUSD':'EURUSD','GBPUSD':'GBPUSD'}>
<s:set value="@dao.positions@positionsO(value)" var="symbol1"/>
    <s:push value="#symbol1">...</s:push>
</s:iterator>
```

But I still have to figure out a way, incase I use a list in iterator, instead of a map as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<s:push value="%{@dao.positions@positionsO(#ordersymbol)}">
```

something similar but taking an expression at whole and evaluate it.